# Access additional fields in _User table

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I ahve a whole lot of additional fields in the `_Use`r table of my Parse backend. But when I try and query this table, the result I get back is a `ParseUser` and this doesnt have my additional fields on it.

How can I access these additional fields?

I have tried this:

```
var result = await (new ParseQuery<ParseObject> ("_User")).FirstOrDefaultAsync ();
```

and it just returns `ParseUser`s.

I really need to access these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out eventually.

Firstly, you will need to subclass `ParseUser` and then map the fields like you would normally.

```
public class User : ParseUser
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    [ParseFieldName("myField")]
    public bool MyField { get { return GetProperty<bool>(); } set { SetProperty<bool>(value); } }
}
```

Then you can run normal `ParseQuery`s like this

```
from u in new ParseQuery<user> ()
where u.Get<bool> ("myField") == true
select u
```

You will then have a 'User' object with the `MyField` property exposed.